# Error While Trying to Use onFormSubmit in Google Apps Script For Google Forms

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-forms

I am trying to set up a few scripts to prevent troll responses on a google form for a check-in at a youth center.

We have had issues with people putting inappropriate names and responses.

While trying to debug and run the code the call stack is thrown **"onFormSubmit @ Code:6"**

Here is the full script.

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  // Define the words to blacklist
  var blacklistedWords = [""];

  // Get the response from the form
    var response = e.response.getItemResponses()[0].getResponse();

  // Check if the response contains any blacklisted words
  for (var i = 0; i < blacklistedWords.length; i++) {
    if (response.indexOf(blacklistedWords[i]) !== -1) {
      // If the response contains a blacklisted word, delete the response
      var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
      var formResponses = form.getResponses();
      var lastResponse = formResponses[formResponses.length - 1];
      var itemResponses = lastResponse.getItemResponses();
      itemResponses[0].getResponse().deleteItemResponse();

      break;
    }
  }
}

function blacklistSingleLetter(e) {
  // Get the response from the form
  var response = e.response.getItemResponses()[0].getResponse();
  
  // Check if the response is a single letter
  if (response.length === 1) {
    // If the response is a single letter, delete the response
    var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
    var formResponses = form.getResponses();
    var lastResponse = formResponses[formResponses.length - 1];
    var itemResponses = lastResponse.getItemResponses();
    itemResponses[0].getResponse().deleteItemResponse();

  }
}

function validatePhoneNumber(e) {
  // Get the response from the form
  var response = e.response.getItemResponses()[0].getResponse();
  
  // Check if the response is a phone number and if it has exactly 10 characters
  if (/^\d{10}$/.test(response)) {
    // If the response is a phone number with exactly 10 characters, do nothing
  } else {
    // If the response is not a phone number with exactly 10 characters, delete the response
    var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
    var formResponses = form.getResponses();
    var lastResponse = formResponses[formResponses.length - 1];
    var itemResponses = lastResponse.getItemResponses();
    itemResponses[0].getResponse().deleteItemResponse();
    
  }
}
```

And if I run the code this error is thrown

**TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'response')
onFormSubmit    @ Code.gs:6**

I have tried asking chatGPT to write some of it and solve the problems with the code, but with no luck. I also looked at the documentation for Apps Script and once again, no luck.

ChatGPT says the error could possibly be from this...

The error you're seeing is likely because the e parameter is not being passed to the onFormSubmit() function. Here's an updated version of the script that should work correctly:

I have set up triggers and everything for the script as well.

Any suggestions and help appreciated

Comment: Where do you call `onFormSubmit()`? Are you passing the parameter?

Comment: On the first line of the `onFormSubmit` function can you add `console.log(e)` and add the output to your answer please?

Comment: You can not run `onFormSubmit(e)` from the script editor.  In that case `e` is undefined.  It will only work if the function is triggered by a form submittal .  In that case the event object `e` contains [Form Submittal Object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#google_forms_events)

Comment: if you were to build you own html form you could eliminate them at the source rather than waiting for form submission

Answer (score 0):

It helps in many situations - however, it is not an ultimate solution - it still happens that even after 5 minutes, event data is not available

```
        const itemResponses = callWithRetry(getItemResponses, event, 10)

        function getItemResponses(event) {
            return event.response.getItemResponses()
        }


          function callWithRetry(fn, params, maxDepth=7, depth = 0){
              try {
                return fn(params);
              } catch(e) {
                if (depth > maxDepth) {
                throw e;
              }
              Utilities.sleep(2 ** depth * 500);
              console.info("Retrying....")
              return callWithRetry(fn, params, maxDepth, depth + 1);
            }
```